# How to get a prompt when switching to normal user account when you are already logged in as root

Tags: password, root, su

I have a requirement (not sure how valid it is). I want to test the password of a normal user (which i just retested). I am logged in as root, and when I switch user from root, it doesn't prompt for a password.

I am not sure, if the `su` command has any option to achieve this.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `su` into that users account from root's account, and then use `su` again. Weird as it sounds, it does ask for a password when `su`'ing into your own account, at least on all systems I could get my hands on to try.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a different console with `[ctrl]+[alt]+F4` and log in normally as the user there.
It will require a password, since it's a standard login session.

edit: @hoe's solution works better in most cases, since it doesn't require physical access or a separate session connection. /edit